# REST API Access Token Issues

Tags: api, rest-api, access

I am trying to use the Magento REST API for a client to get details of customers, and orders, etc. I have setup a REST Consumer and I am trying to obtain an oauth access token and having issues. I have found a API call http://clients_magento_shop/api/rest/integration/access/token in the documentation, passing the username and password in the body, however I am getting the following error "Request does not match any route" - its like the API resource doesn't exist.

The application I am building will be a background task, so having the user login to Magento to authorize the request token isn't an option. So I have tried to fake a login and authorization by GET and POST operations through C#. This works great on a standard Magento setup but because the client is using a hosting single signon provider, I cant get to the login page to obtain the Form-Key, which is part of the login POST. Therefore I am stuck.

Comment: In this video, I describe rest API access levels https://youtu.be/9OpjTwifhaE

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass url like,

> http://clients_magento_shop/rest/V1/integration/admin/token

Pass body method like this,

**Post Method:**

```
Body:
{
    "username":"admin",
    "password":"admin123"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Rakesh. There is something very weird here. I do have a access token provided by the client. If I use this do call customers or any other resource to format of the url is:  http://clients_magento_shop/api/rest/resource however all the doc's and your example has http://clients_magento_shop/rest/V1/resource. If I use your format I get a 404 Note Found error :-(

Comment: Bit late to the party, perhaps, but anyway: the api/rest format is Magento 1, whereas rest/V1 is Magento 2.